# Thinkster MEAN Stack tutorial - Getting User Input: Post not getting generated

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am in the section called "Getting User Input". I am clicking the "Post" button to generate a new post, but no new post appears. There is code to prevent the post from being generated when the textbox input is blank, but there is no post generated even when I type in a title in the textbox.

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
    {{post.title}} - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    <div>
    <form ng-submit="addPost()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="title"></input>
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews',[]);
app.controller('MainCtrl',[
'$scope',
function($scope){
    $scope.posts = [
        {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
        {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
        {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
        {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
        {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
    ];

    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === ''){return;}
        $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, upvotes: 0});
        $scope.title = '';
    };
}]);
```

I tried to debug it with my limited knowledge (I am a beginner with the MEAN stack), and rechecked the tutorial code, which seems to be identical.

This is the tutorial link:https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial

Comment: that should work, are you filling in the title field before submitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your html code. The ng-repeat div is not closed properly.

```html
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
  {{post.title}} - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
  <div>
```

Should be:

```html
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
  {{post.title}} - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
</div>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9yUE6W9hX5uf2k8EFzl)'s a plunker with it working.

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that. Is there an html checker for this, since Sublime text doesn't by default explicitly highlight this error.

Comment: Thanks for introducing Plunker as well.

Comment: I always found it easiest to spot this kind of errors with code formatting since the indentation would be off. I think sublime offers that.:)